# elasticsearch phrase prefix stops finding

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch phrase prefix queries for some autocompletions.
It usually works pretty well but sometimes doesn't find an incomplete word anymore, although with one more or one less letter it does find it.

For example: it does find something containing "Anomalie" with the query "Anomal" and the query "Anomalie", but finds nothing with "Anomali". Which is really weird for a user experience!

My previous googlings made me try disabling stopwords, but it didn't solve my problem. I tried using the stopwords config in the analyzer and as a filter.

To reproduce:

Index creation, configuration and adding a document:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/' -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "analysis" : {
        "filter" : {
          "french_stemmer" : {
            "type" : "stemmer",
            "name" : "light_french"
          },
          "no_stop" : {
            "type" : "stop",
            "stopwords" : "_none_"
          }
        },
        "analyzer" : {
          "default" : {
            "type" : "custom",
            "stopwords" : "_none_",
            "filter" : [ "standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "word_delimiter", "french_stemmer", "no_stop" ],
            "tokenizer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/test/1' -d '{
    "title": "Anomalie"
}'
```

Those queries find the document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
        "title" : "Anomalie"
      }
    }
  }
}
'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "title" : {
        "query": "Anomalie",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "title" : {
        "query": "Anomal",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

But this one finds no document and has no error:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/elastictests/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "title" : {
        "query": "Anomali",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occuring because the [french_stemmer](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/french/stemmer.html) stems *Anomalie* => *anomal*.

However   *anomali* would not be stemmed to *anomal*.

So indexed term for *Anomalie* => *anomal*

Similarly when the query term is *Anomalie* the search term gets analyzed to *anomal* and it matches on title.

However when query is  "Anomali"  it gets analyzed to "anomali"  that is no stemming occurs. Since the indexed term is "anomal"  there is no match prefix or otherwise .

If you remove the stemmer from the custom analyzer described in OP you should get the desired results for this specific use-case

Example:

```
get elastictests/_analyze?field=title&text=Anomalie

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "**anomal**",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 8,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}

get elastictests/_analyze?field=title&text=Anomali
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "**anomali**",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 7,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
```